# How do I execute a find command with multiple iname matchers in Go?

Tags: shell, go, command

I need to execute this sort of command through the Go programming language:

`find /some/dir/path -type f \( -iname \*.zip -o -iname \*.tar -o -iname \*.rar \)`

I discovered exec.Command and tried various ways of executing the `find` command,
e.g.

```
exec.Command("find", dir, "-type", "f", "\\( -iname \\*.zip -o -iname \\*.tar -o -iname \\*.rar \\)")
exec.Command("find", dir, "-type", "f", "-iname", "*.zip", "-o", "-iname", "*.tar", "-o", "-iname", "*.rar")
exec.Command("find", dir, "-type", "f", "\\(", "-iname", "\\*.zip", "-o", "-iname", "\\*.tar", "-o", "-iname", "\\*.rar", "\\)")
```

None of the above have worked for me.  Is there a way to do this, or am I just going to have to issue 3 separate find commands in Go?

Comment: If you are trying to find files with specific file extensions, consider using [Walk](http://godoc.org/path/filepath#Walk) instead of executing a command.

Comment: What's wrong with this question?  Why have I received a downvote?

Comment: Basic questions sometimes get downvoted around here. This is also a common mistake, but it's hard to search for. Don't worry about it, have an upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec.Command` isn't a shell, so you don't need to escape special characters in your command. Pass each argument in exactly how you want it processed by the command.

```
exec.Command("find", dir, "-type", "f", "(", "-iname", "*.zip", "-o", "-iname", "*.tar", "-o", "-iname", "*.rar", ")")
```